# I have a for loop to count prime numbers, how do I count the number of primes being generated?

Tags: java

In this example I have code to count the prime numbers between 2 - 130. I have been tasked to increment a count of the number of primes. I'm not sure how to go about this?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i=0; i<130; i++){
            if(isPrime(i)){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

        if (n == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: Declare a variable counter, of type int, before the loop. Initialize it to 0. In your `if` block, increment it. After the loop, it contains the number of prime numbers.

Comment: Consider changing your THEN block from printing "its a prime" to increase a counter declared in front of the loop.

Comment: I recommend reading tutorials. Incredibly simple questions like this don't really belong on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add an integer variable, which in your for loop, when you find a prime number, you need to increment, just like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfPrimes=0;               // the variable to count the primes
    for (int i=0; i<130; i++){
        if(isPrime(i)){
            System.out.println(i);
            numberOfPrimes++;           //incrementing for each prime found
        }
    }
    System.out.println("number of primes is: " + numberOfPrimes); //showing the number of primes found.
}

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

    if (n == 1) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since, you want to count the number of primes generated. Just declare a variable of type integer, like say counter and initialize its value to zero. Then when you encounter a prime number in the `if` block, instead of printing it, increment the value of the counter. After all the numbers have been checked, print the value of the counter. Like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<130; i++){
            if(isPrime(i)){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {

        if (n == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;

    }

}
```

Also, if you just want to check the numbers from 2-130, then why start the `for` loop from `i=0`. You should start it from `i=2`. It will help save some CPU time (not that much important in this case though). Also to save more CPU time, you can search for a prime until square root of the number, instead of looping untill the half of the potential prime.